# Who is the voice actor of Scissor Runner in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

Does anyone recognise the voice of the ancient dragon called Scissor Runner?
I'm pretty sure I've heard it before but I can't seem to find any information on that matter, except for one person saying it is Kamikawa Takaya, but in comparison they sound very different to me.

I continued searching and this is what I additionally came up with:

I know only some french words but as far as I understand it, [the person here asks the same question like me](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-98-656415-1-0-1-0-je-recherche-le-nom-d-un-seiyuu.htm) and someone suggests Ikeda Shuuichi.

While my personal theory, after comparing several voices, is: it's the same voice as Laxus. Konishi Katsuyuki.

Unfortunately still all of them are mere guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Although not officially confirmed, the rumour on MAL is that it's [Takaya Kamikawa](http://myanimelist.net/people/5993/Takaya_Kamikawa).

He's mostly known from the voice of Anti-Spiral in Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann.

Comment: That is pretty much the only thing that shows up using google and it is just one persons guess. I compared them already and honestly I think they are very different. Sorry I didn't mention that before.

Answer (score 1):

I also think it's Katsuyuki Konishi (i.e. Laxus). I've always been very adept at recognizing voices and the first moment Scissor Runner spoke, I knew it was him.

There is absolutely no way it's Takaya Kamikawa. Anime crews always "recycle" their voice actors - when they need a bit part or 1-2 episode character (like Scissor Runner) voiced, they use someone who's already been in the series.

Scissor Runner and Levia, for example, are Laxus and Bickslow; Atlas Flame is Byro, Byro Cracy and Jose Porla; Motherglare has 13 other roles (including Alzack); Rock Dragon has 9 other roles (including Droy); while Zirconis is also Arcadios and Capricorn.

Comment: Any sources to go along with these statements?